# VB .Net - TransactionScope aborts when Using is outside Try/Catch

Tags: vb.net, transactions, try-catch, transactionscope, using-statement

The following method is called from within a loop:

```
Public Sub ExampleAbort()

        Using trans As New TransactionScope(TransactionScopeOption.Required, New TransactionOptions With {.IsolationLevel = IsolationLevel.ReadUncommitted, .Timeout = New TimeSpan(0, 10, 0)})
            Try

                DoSomeTransationalStuffHere()

                trans.Complete()

            Catch ex As Exception
                ShowError(ex.Message)
                Throw
            End Try
        End Using
End Sub
```

This will lead to the DTS aborting the transaction after the first item. If I place the 'Using' statement within the Try/Catch block, everything works. Can someone please explain this behavior? I was under the assumption that Using-blocks ALWAYS Dispose'd no matter how you return from a method.

Best regards,
Goran

Comment: So do you have any exceptions being thrown when the code is executed?

Comment: @Szymon from the OP's description, the exact problem seems clear: he is getting an error in New TransactionScope... which cannot be catched by the Using statement and that's why it should be included inside the Try...Catch part. The exact situation is more or less irrelevant as far as the referred cases are very descriptive: it works inside the Try...Catch but it does not work outside it; why is this the case? Because you are getting an error in the only part being outside the Try block.

Comment: I get the TransactionAbortedException for the trans.Complete statement for the second item if the Using block starts outside the Try/Catch block. I -think- this is caused by the trans not being disposed of properly for some reason. No exception is raised from DoSomeTransactionalStuffHere(). If I move the Using inside the Try/Catch it all works.